# Extract artifactId and version number from Maven-generated Jar

Tags: maven, version

If have a bunch of Jar files created by Maven. Their name includes the artifactId and the version number. I want to extract the artifactId and the version number from the Jar file names. However, it turns out this is far from easy. I have file names such as `qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol-7.0.6.jar` where there's two parts that look like a version number (`0-8` and `7.0.6`) but only the latter is the version. Then there's `adminpages-4.11.0-beta-20191212-150315-7eec2eb4c.jar` where `4.11.0-beta-20191212-150315-7eec2eb4c` is the version. Therefore my question is whether there is a safe and reliable way to extract the version number from a Jar file name?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail which kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to list the used libraries in a web application. I scan the WEB-INF/lib folder and then need to extract the names and version from the file names as separate pieces. But it seems there is no generic way to do it right in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

No.

File names are usually of the form

```
artifactId-version-classifier.extension
```

if the classifier is not empty, otherwise

```
artifactId-version.extension
```

All three elements (`artifactId`, `version`, `classifier`) could be arbitrary strings.

If you need to find the coordinates to a given jar, there are other, more reliable methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "If you need to find the coordinates to a given jar, there are other, more reliable methods."   the other more reliable methods?  Are there any that dont require using maven?

Comment: @JohnCamerin You can look into the JAR. JARs often contain their coordinates in METAINF or a pom.properties file. You can also compute the sha1 of the file and look it up in MavenCentral.